# Jest snapshot tests <!---->

Tags: jestjs, snapshot

I am writing Jest snapshot tests. My snapshot files sometimes contain `<!---->`. What does it mean?

Example:

```
<div>
  <!---->

  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the concatenation of the start `<!--` and end `-->` of a HTML comment tag. Refer to [HTML documentation here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp).